# Why doesn't PostgreSQL increase the last_value on the id_sequence when merging an instance?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In a previous question, I was wondering why I was getting an Integrity Error from SA when merging an instance with an ID for the first time into the database (injecting fixture data).

However, I learned to account for the problem by calling with the highest index I'm injecting:

```
select setval('my_items_id_seq', {id});
```

However, this didn't solve the underlying problem, which is what I'm struggling with now. Why doesn't merge call nextval() on the sequence when inserting a new row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object already has its PK attribute set, then the ID sequence will not be used and therefore not incremented because there is no reason for the database to perform an implicit `insert into mytable (id, ...) values ((select nextval from mytable_id_seq), ...)`.

Are you sure you need to be doing a `merge` instead of an `add` to your `session`?  If you are really inserting, I would think that is more of an `add` operation.  If you are simply reusing an object that is still in memory, but added earlier and possibly changed in the database now, then `merge` is appropriate.

Comment: wberry is correct. You only use merge to bring in disconnected objects  or objects from another session. If these are `new` object you've created then you need to use `add`. Keep in mind that using `setval` forces the sequence's current value regardless of what ids may already exist in your table - if you haven't cleared your table data before adding your new objects you could get key overlap and integrity erros.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue of IntegrityErrors in PostgreSQL until I found this post.  I decided to stick to the following rule:  **if the object does not exist in the database, do NOT specify a primary key with db.add() or db.merge().**

Here are the examples I used to figure out what wberry meant.

```
# Suppose the next value of rows_id_seq will be 33.
# You run the following code.
db.add(Row(id=35))
# Since you specified a primary key, SQLAlchemy will NOT increment rows_id_seq,
# so the next value of rows_id_seq will still be 33.
db.add(Row())
# The next value of rows_id_seq will be 34
db.add(Row())
# The next value of rows_id_seq will be 35
db.add(Row())
db.query(Row.id).all() # Uh-oh
# (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rows_pkey"
# Key (id)=(35) already exists.
```

Here is an example using *db.merge()*.

```
# Suppose the next value of rows_id_seq will be 1.
# You run the following code.
db.merge(Row(id=1))
db.merge(Row(id=2))
db.merge(Row(id=3))
# Since you specified a primary key, SQLAlchemy will NOT increment rows_id_seq,
# so the next value of rows_id_seq will still be 1.
db.merge(Row())
db.query(Row.id).all() # Uh-oh
# (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rows_pkey"
# Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```